# Are there 2 pindi's in vaishno devi for darshan?

Tags: temple, darshan

I noticed that there are 2 queues for darshan at bhavan, but after entering the cave in one queue I did not see the other queue anywhere till exit. But my friends who were in the other queue also had Darshan of Pindi. So I am confused whether there are 2 sets of Pindi's for darshan - one for each queue?

Or if there's only single Pindi darshan, then how do they manage both queue's because I did not see the other queue anywhere till exit.

Comment: I have also visited Vaishno Devi temple. There is only one Pindi but there are two queue going towards same Pindi fro different directions.

Comment: What is a Pindi? Is that the main deity in the temple? I don't understand the term here. Please post a near English translation for the word.

Comment: @NogShine yes the term Pindi here means the main deity in the temple, which is in the form of 3 stones (representing 3 goddesses).

Comment: you are right Mohit...i visited the shrine and felt the same because there were two queues and they never inter mingled or met and both were going into diffrent sanctum-santorum or so it seems.

Answer (score 3):

There is only one Holy pindi (natural rock formation) in the form of three pindis representing three goddesses Kaali, Lakshmi and Saraswati.

From the official website of [Mata Vaishnodevi Shrine board](https://www.maavaishnodevi.org/darshan.aspx),

> It is reiterated that Darshans inside the Holy Cave are in the form of natural rock formations called Pindies. There are no statues, pictures or idols inside. All along the track and at the Bhawan, there are many photographs explaining the nature of Darshans inside the Holy Cave. Yatries should observe these carefully since these are meant to guide them towards the final Darshans in the Holy Cave.

The above paragraph is given in bold in the website.

But there are other darshanas inside the holy cave. From the [other page](https://www.maavaishnodevi.org/other_darshans.aspx) of the same website,

> The Holy Cave is around 98 feet long. Besides the main Darshans of the Pindies inside the Cave, there are various other Darshans, outside and inside the Holy Cave and around the Holy Pindies.

It is also stated that the original holy cave will be closed during peak seasons and new tunnels are used when there is rush.

> Yatris may however note that most of these Darshans are possible only if the original cave is used. However, owing to the heavy rush, usually the new tunnels are used and the original cave is opened only during the lean seasons. Yatries desirous of having all the Darshans are advised to formulate their programme to correspond with the lean seasons.

So, it is possible that your friends have gone through the tunnels which you didn't go.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Nog. Still what I want to know is, are there more than one deity (in form of 3 pindi's) for darshan? To rephrase, is it possible that I did darshan of some other pindi's while my friends did darshan of other pindi's?

Comment: No, there is only one Vaishno Devi Mata Pindi (in the form of three mothers) for Darshan. It is for sure by the bold passage on the site. But there are some other Darshans inside the cave for photographs, Ganesha, Hanuman. It is possible that you took one tunnel and they took another one. Perhaps one of the tunnels are shorter than the other (i.e., it is probable they are not of the same length).

Comment: I have noticed that in many Hindu temples are two queues. One is "fast track lane". You pay more, you wait less.

Comment: yes @JulioOlivieras you're right. But in this case, both the queues are similar and anyone can go to any one of the queues.